# login problem with ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, login-attempts

i have created login page which sends ajax request to a php page for login verification.
On that php page i m creating session, and sending response as per login verification.
if user is authenticated i m redirecting it to home page from java script from where i send ajax. but on that homepage i cant get that session object... why? can u tell me solution to retrieve that session on home page

Comment: Solution is in debugging. try to make if without ajax first. check cookies and session id's

Comment: Whether have you used session_start() in home page.

Comment: Help us to help you: Provide some code!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I do it the right way, but it works for me this way (I hope I didn't forget anything):

Here's what my login.php does :

```
header('Content-type: text/json');

// here : import files I need

session_start();

// here : load some parameters into session variables
// here : init mysql connection
// here : get user and password from $_POST and check them against the database

// If the user can't connect, return an error to the client
if ( ! $ok )
{
    echo '{ "ok": "N" }';
    exit;
}

$_SESSION['user']    = $user;

echo '{ "ok": "O" }';
```

?>

Then when I access another php file, here's how it begins :

```
header('Content-type: text/json');
// again, required files go here

session_start();

if ( ! isset($_SESSION['user'] )) {
        echo '{ "ok": "N" }';
    exit;
}

$user=$_SESSION['user'];
....
```

Every ajax call I make checks if the result tells me the user isn't connected, and returns to the login page if he isn't.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myphp.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: somedatatopost,
    success: function(pRep){
      if (!pRep) {
        alert("No response from the server.");
        return;
      }
      if (pRep.ok=="N") {
        window.location = '/index.html';
        return;
      }
      // here is where I handle a successful response
    }
  });
```

For the login ajax call, I have :

```
[....]
// here is where I handle a successful response
window.location='mynewpage.html'
```